# Is there a time when Exception can be nothing?

Tags: vb.net, exception

while trying to maintain someone else's code I found this little gem:

```
 Catch ex As Exception
   If Not ex Is Nothing Then
     ...
   End If
Finally
```

Is there a time when this could happen that I am unaware of?  Should I be adding these to my code?

Comment: Excellent question but I would say no. Looks like a waste of code.

Comment: `Throw Nothing` is illegal - `Throw operand must derive from System.Exception`  but yes, interesting question

Comment: It is just code from a programmer that didn't know what he was doing.  That doesn't make it legitimate code.  There are probably a lot of other null checks that you need to delete from that code.  That kind that *shouldn't* hide errors.  Never hide a NullReferenceException, you'd hide a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try this:

```
Try
    Dim x As Exception = Nothing
    Throw x
Catch ex As Exception
    Debug.Print(ex.ToString())
End Try
```

`ex` will be a `System.NullReferenceException`.  The [`Throw` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty79csek.aspx) docs don't mention what happens if you pass a null reference, but the [`OpCodes.Throw`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.throw.aspx) docs say:

> NullReferenceException is thrown if the object reference is a null reference.

So, I believe the answer is that `ex` can never be `Nothing`.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a `GoTo` statement which resets the `Exception ex` thrown to `Nothing`, the code seems redundant since the only case in which the control enters the `Catch` is when there is an Exception thrown from `Try` block while the `If Not` condition compares default value of Nothing which equals Exception. Meaning the condition would never be satisfied and stands redundant except for some GoTo control which assigns a different Exception to Nothing,